# bigQuery and GA-Premium Integration: How to use IP filters in bigQuery (to exclude internal traffic) when exported data from unfiltered view in GA

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

We have recently connected GA Premium to bigQuery to export all unsampled data from 1 property and 1 view.  We decided to use the unfiltered view within our clients single property to make sure we get all data, however we still want to apply the "exclude internal IP ranges" filter to this data set in bigQuery. Is there a way to build a filter or query that removes internal visits from certain IP ranges or will we need to change the GA view that is connected to bigQuery (since only 1 view per property can be integrated)?

Thanks!
Amin

Answer (score 3):

BigQuery will not house individual IP info because GA tracker attempts to preserve individual user privacy. You cannot filter data using a WHERE clause in BigQuery for i.p. information.

Answer (score 0):

In BigQuery (BQ), you can create [views](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/querying-data#views), that are virtual tables created from a SQL query. Since you can't [delete or update data](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables#deletingrows), you can either delete and recreate the table or query the data and send the results to a new table.

Looking at the [BQ export schema](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en), I couldn't find a field that refers to the 'user IP address', I only see a 'geoNetwork' information.

So, if the field you're looking for is not exported to BQ, you might need to apply the "exclude internal IP ranges" filter in GA before exporting data.